# Windows volume control volume 0 not silent

Tags: windows, audio

I have some headphones without a volume control. I use the Windows 7 volume control. Volume 0 isn't silent. What's going on?

Comment: "isn't silent" is not that defined. What do you hear? Do you hear sound from the system? Do you just hear some static noise?

Comment: If I play music, I can still hear the music.

Comment: Does the volume change in general? Does it become more quiet or does it not change at all?

Comment: Good question. Should have said, yes volume control otherwise works okay.

Comment: Do you have the latest driver for your audio-card installed? Also, how are the headphones connected to the pc?

Comment: Yes, Realtek High Definition Audio. Headphones by 3.5mm stereo jack to the front.